# ASP.NET character count of text box different than server side text box character count

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, textarea

I have a javascript function to display the remaining character count to the user on the page.
When I validate the length server side prior to a database insert to make sure it is not greater than the column length I'm actually getting a different count.

Researching online it appears that javascript counts new lines / CR and maybe some other special characters differently than C# does.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

This is my javascript on the client side:

```js
 <script>
        var textarea = document.getElementById('TxtComment');

        window.onload = textareaLengthCheck();

        function textareaLengthCheck() {
            var maxChars = 4000;
            var textArea = textarea.value.length;
            var charactersLeft = maxChars - textArea;
            var count = document.getElementById('cmt-characters-left');
            count.innerHTML = "Characters left: " + charactersLeft + " of " + maxChars;
        }

        textarea.addEventListener('keyup', textareaLengthCheck, false);
        textarea.addEventListener('keydown', textareaLengthCheck, false);

    </script>
```

Tried adding this - but it seemed to make the problem even worse:

```js
 var textArea = textarea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, "").length;
```

Comment: This particular issue has been driving me crazy for 20 years. It is a small but wonderful illustration of dysfunction in the world of standards. It's not a JavaScript issue; it's the way the DOM works. The browser "normalizes" the textarea value by treating all line breaks as being 1 character in length, even if the break involves CR and LF both.

Comment: and it gets even more hairy ball, since we have a database, and client side (desktop) software can edit some of those text areas, and then so can a Android Phone (native application) on the android. Those Andriod text boxes use/have a single LF for return in those text boxes. Our final solution was to replace all CRLF to LF, and then replace all LF back to a CRLF. Thus Android side might have edits with by desktop software (CRLF)). And edits by Anrioid (only LF). So we change any CRLF in the text to a LF. Now we have only LF for new lines, and then we convert all LF's back to CRLF.

Comment: And to make matters even worse, that database is also used by a asp.net web site, and again allows editing of those text areas. So, 3 platforms (web, desktop, and Android). And none of them have a agreed common format for a new line in text!!!

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal somewhere on an external drive I've got some JavaScript code that *partially* solves this. The code is from the mid-2000s. In my opinion all the confusion makes the `maxlength` property useless, because by the time the content makes it to the database the size can't be trusted. IE used to get it "wrong", which meant that it counted the CR characters, and actually worked better.

Comment: Yes! - we not even gone down the road of browers also having a difference!!! Thankfully standards for browsers are now rather good, and the fact that Edge uses chrome engine has helped boatloads here. But, man, that's opening a can of worms and tossing in a huge ball of wax into this!!!  But, I can say, I don't support the older Windows IE browser anymore, but web land still is a messy affair, but is getting better and better all the time due to browser standards having vast improved in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
Javascrit was counting the "\r\n" as 1 character, C# was counting as 2 characters.
On the server side C# validation I changed it to this:

```
TxtComment.Text = this.TxtComment.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
if (this.TxtComment.Text.Trim().Length > 4000)
{
    ... your Validation message here ...
}
```